# File referenced in tests could be found on local build/test but not using teamservices

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, build, azure-devops

i'm new to the .net core build process, so my question might be simple but i could't figure it out up to now. So any hint would be appreciated!

I've create a Visual Studio solution following this structure

`MoCap1 (the solution) 
- src
  - C3D (my main project)
    - project.json (etc.)
- test
  - C3D.Tests (the corresponding test project)
    - project.json (etc.)
    - C3DParserTests.cs (the file containing the test mentioned below)`

This structure is used on disc and in the solution explorer in Visual Studio 2015

In C3DParserTests.cs i've defined the following test:

```
        [Fact]
        public void Parse()
        {
            /*
             * positive tests
             */
            C3DParser parser = new C3DParser();
            C3DModel model = parser.Parse(File.ReadAllBytes(@"Data\HDM_bd_01-01_01_120.c3d"));

            Assert.NotNull(model);

            // check header info
            Assert.Equal(2, model.ParameterSectionStart);
        }
```

As you can see a .c3d file is referenced. When using Visual Studio for testing the file can be found and the test is successful. When using teamservices and my build process i get the following error:

```
xUnit.net .NET CLI test runner (64-bit .NET Core win81-x64)
  Discovering: C3D.Tests
  Discovered:  C3D.Tests
  Starting:    C3D.Tests
    C3D.Tests.C3DParserTests.Parse [FAIL]
      System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\a\1\s\Data\HDM_bd_01-01_01_120.c3d'.
      Stack Trace:
           at System.IO.Win32FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, FileStream parent)
           at System.IO.Win32FileSystem.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, FileStream parent)
           at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
           at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllBytes(String path)
           at System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(String path)
        C:\a\1\s\MoCap1\test\C3D.Tests\C3DParserTests.cs(22,0): at C3D.Tests.C3DParserTests.Parse()
    C3D.Tests.C3DParserTests.ParseNegative [FAIL]
      System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\a\1\s\Data\HDM_bd_01-01_01_120.c3d'.
      Stack Trace:
           at System.IO.Win32FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, FileStream parent)
           at System.IO.Win32FileSystem.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, FileStream parent)
           at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
           at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllBytes(String path)
           at System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(String path)
        C:\a\1\s\MoCap1\test\C3D.Tests\C3DParserTests.cs(40,0): at C3D.Tests.C3DParserTests.ParseNegative()
  Finished:    C3D.Tests
=== TEST EXECUTION SUMMARY ===
   C3D.Tests  Total: 4, Errors: 0, Failed: 2, Skipped: 0, Time: 0.349s
SUMMARY: Total: 1 targets, Passed: 0, Failed: 1.
Process completed with exit code 1.
```

It makes sense somehow since the path

> C:\a\1\s\Data\HDM_bd_01-01_01_120.c3d

doesn't exist. This is the output for the build step where you can see the correct path

```
Done Building Project "C:\a\1\s\MoCap1\src\C3D\C3D.xproj" (default targets).
The target "_ConvertPdbFiles" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter\Xamarin.Common.targets (34,37)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "_CollectPdbFiles" listed in an AfterTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter\Xamarin.Common.targets (34,70)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "_CollectMdbFiles" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter\Xamarin.Common.targets (41,38)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "_CopyMdbFiles" listed in an AfterTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter\Xamarin.Common.targets (41,71)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
Project "C:\a\1\s\MoCap1\MoCap1.sln" (1) is building "C:\a\1\s\MoCap1\test\C3D.Tests\C3D.Tests.xproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory ".\bin\".
  Creating directory ".\obj\Release\".
CoreCompile:
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe build "C:\a\1\s\MoCap1\test\C3D.Tests" --configuration Release --no-dependencies
  Project C3D.Tests (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because expected outputs are missing
  Compiling C3D.Tests for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
  Compilation succeeded.
      0 Warning(s)
      0 Error(s)
  Time elapsed 00:00:01.8894809

Done Building Project "C:\a\1\s\MoCap1\test\C3D.Tests\C3D.Tests.xproj" (default targets).
Done Building Project "C:\a\1\s\MoCap1\MoCap1.sln" (default targets).
Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:43.29
```

The dotNet build step for testing produces the following output:

```
Starting: Run dotnet
******************************************************************************
dotnet test C:\a\1\s\MoCap1\test\C3D.Tests -xml testresultsC3D.xml
Project C3D (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because expected outputs are missing
Compiling C3D for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
Compilation succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time elapsed 00:00:01.8492346
Project C3D.Tests (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because dependencies changed
Compiling C3D.Tests for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
Compilation succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time elapsed 00:00:01.7167452
```

Could you give me any advice how to solve this issue?

Best regards,

Nils

Comment: How do you create xunittest project for main project? You can provide the detail steps or share a simple project on the OneDrive.

Comment: I referred to this article (https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html) to create xunit project. It builds fine. (related code  [Fact]
        public void ReadFileTest()
        {
            byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(@"Data2\tt.txt");
            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
            Assert.Equal("hello", result);
        }). What's the detail of your build steps, how do you specify working folder of Command line step?

Comment: To run test, I uses Command line step (dotnet test).

Comment: What's the structure of your project?

Comment: Is the "HDM_bd_01-01_01_120.c3d" file generated by the build?